# Mule ESB 3.8 Http post form-data with file and text

Tags: api, file, mule, esb, form-data

My requirement is to call REST API with a file attachment and a text parameter (in body). When I use Postman it works fine. Screenshot of the postman request looks like this.

[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSAZR.png)

But with the following Mule code, I get 400 - bad request response. Here is my Mule code snippet.

```
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.fileContent]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<set-attachment attachmentName="file" value="byte-array-contents" contentType="application/txt" doc:name="Attachment"/>
<set-attachment attachmentName="name" value="1dildfnnl" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attachment"/>
<set-payload value="#[null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Please help on how to pass in Mule file as attachment and parameter in request body?

Comment: Shouldn't the file attachment value be "payload"? In any case, I recommend enabling wire logging in mule and getting the curl request from postman to execute with "-v" and compare both versions to figure out what causes the 400.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did http wire enabled and I receive following detail error. I have also added what the content type for two parameters I was trying to pass in the body. As you can see file mimetype is text/csv. But rejection code says it is text/plain. 

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 
 {"code":400,"body":["file mimetype text/plain not permitted"]}

Comment: Found solution to my problem. Used groovy script to resolve this. check this link. https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-10439